# java ключевое слово synchronized

Tags: java, synchronized

есть следующий код:

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int n = 40;
            System.out.println("Start " + Thread.currentThread());
            Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(fibonachi(n));

            System.out.println(n + " : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000.0 + " сек");
            System.out.println("End " + Thread.currentThread());
        }
    }).start();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int n = 31;
            System.out.println("Start " + Thread.currentThread());
            Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(fibonachi(n));

            System.out.println(n + " : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000.0 + " сек");
            System.out.println("End " + Thread.currentThread());
        }
    }).start();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int n = 45;
            System.out.println("Start " + Thread.currentThread());
            Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(fibonachi(n));

            System.out.println(n + " : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000.0 + " сек");
            System.out.println("End " + Thread.currentThread());
        }
    }).start();
}

  static long fibonachi(long n){

    if (n == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    if (n == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return fibonachi(n - 1) + fibonachi(n - 2);
    }
}
}
```

Если его запустить будут запущены 3 потока и они начнут выполняться параллельно. Например:

```
Start Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
Start Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
1346269
31 : 0.006 сек
End Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
Start Thread[Thread-2,5,main]
102334155
40 : 0.722 сек
End Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
1134903170
45 : 6.841 сек
End Thread[Thread-2,5,main]
```

Но, если к методу fibonachi добавить ключевое слово synchronized
То выполняется максимум 1 поток и то не всегда

```
Start Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
Start Thread[Thread-2,5,main]
Start Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
1346269
31 : 0.155 сек
End Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
```

А дальше программа "зависает".
Как понимаю это происходит из-за того, что потоки не могут понять кто следующий будет исполнять этот метод?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Остальные потоки не зависают. Они выполняются, но, во-первых, гораздо медленнее, а во-вторых из-за `synchronized` не параллельно, а по очереди.

То что монитор освободился и программа продолжает работать легко увидеть, если запустить ее в отладчике и приостановить после того как первый поток завершил выполнение.

Ну или если подождать:

```
Start Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
Start Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
Start Thread[Thread-2,5,main]
102334155
40 : 10.557 сек
End Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
1134903170
45 : 129.391 сек
End Thread[Thread-2,5,main]
1346269
31 : 129.528 сек
End Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
```

### synchronized

Это ключевое слово на методе означает, что только один поток может вызвать данную функцию. Если несколько потоков пытаются делать это параллельно, то только первый выполняют функцию, а остальные ждут, пока первый на закончит. После того, как первый поток полностью завершит выполнение функции `fibonachi` (включая все рекурсивные вызовы), какой-то один из ожидающих потоков, сможет продолжить. А уже после него третий.

### Замедление выполнения

Дело в том, что операции которые выполняются JVM, для того чтобы метод с `synchronized` работал так как должен, далеко не бесплатные. Они приводят к ощутимому уменьшению производительности.

Это видно даже по скорости выполнения одного потока.

Вот что показывают замеры времени вызова `fibonachi` для таких трех случаев:

1. без синхронизации вообще (`a_nosynchronize`)
2. с синхронизацией только самого внешнего вызова (`b_outersynchronize`)
3. с синхронизацией всех рекурсивных вызовов (`c_allsynchronize`)

```
Benchmark                                    Mode  Cnt    Score    Error  Units
MonitorReentryBenchmark.a_nosynchronize     thrpt    6  262.763 ± 16.314  ops/s
MonitorReentryBenchmark.b_outersynchronize  thrpt    6  260.950 ± 17.297  ops/s
MonitorReentryBenchmark.c_allsynchronize    thrpt    6   53.909 ±  3.928  ops/s
```

Как видим добавление синхронизации для рекурсивных вызовов существенно замедляет скорость работы. Тест конечно синтетический, но все же определенная закономерность видна. И нужно учитывать, что в этом тесте все происходит в одном потоке и не учитываются никакие эффекты связанные с собственно многопоточностью (как то синхронизация памяти), которыми, по-видимому, объясняется гораздо более сильное замедление нежели в этом тесте.

Тестировал с помощью такого [jmh](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-performance/jmh.html) теста:

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@Fork(value = 1)
@Warmup(iterations = 1, time = 500, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 6, time = 2000, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
public class MonitorReentryBenchmark {

  @Benchmark
  public void a_nosynchronize(Blackhole bh) {
    bh.consume(nosync(30));
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void b_outersynchronize(Blackhole bh) {
    bh.consume(outersync(30));
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void c_allsynchronize(Blackhole bh) {
    bh.consume(allsync(30));
  }

  static long nosync(long n) {

    if (n == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return nosync(n - 1) + nosync(n - 2);
    }
  }

  synchronized static long outersync(long n) {

    if (n == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return nosync(n - 1) + nosync(n - 2);
    }
  }

  synchronized static long allsync(long n) {

    if (n == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return allsync(n - 1) + allsync(n - 2);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Добавление ключевого слова `synchronized` в метод `fibonachi()` по сути означает, что поток который "захватил [монитор](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization))" (начал использовать) метод `fibonachi()` не будет давать возможности другим потокам его захватывать и остальные потоки будут ожидать завершения (освобождения монитора) захватившим потоком.

Небольшой трюк есть в самом методе `fibonachi()` - поскольку он рекурсивный, но фокус только кажется фокусом. В Java многократный захват монитора одним и тем же потоком разрешен, поэтому поток сам себя не будет ждать.